# Adverbs - the difference between 恐らくand 多分

Tags: grammar, adverbs

Is 多分 more neutral:

> 明日 多分 行く - I might go tomorrow

While 恐らく has a negative nuance:

> 姫を閉じ込めるとしたら 恐らく天守閣だ - If I were to lock up the princess, I'd dare say it would be the castle tower

OR

> 明日 恐らく 行く - I might [unfortunately] go tommorrow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[dictionary.goo.ne.jp](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%A4%9A%E5%88%86/#jn-138562) explains the differences thusly (written in Japanese):

「多分（おそらく）今日は帰りが遅くなります」「Aチームが多分（おそらく）優勝するだろう」など、推量の意では相通じて用いられる。◇両語は過去の推量にも用いる。「あれは多分おととしの暮れだったと思う」「彼はおそらくその事実を知っていたであろう」◇「おそらく」は、その原義から、悪いほうの可能性が高いと推量する気持ちが残り、「おそらく後悔するだろう」のような用法が中心となる。◇「多分」の方がややぞんざいで、「おそらく」の方があらたまった丁寧な言い方になる。「多分彼は来ないだろう」「おそらく彼は来ないでしょう」◇類似の語に「きっと」がある。口頭語で、「Aチームがきっと優勝するだろう」のように、「多分」や「おそらく」と同様に用いるが、「きっと」の方が実現の確かさが強い。

Edit: My rough translation - In sentences such as 「多分（おそらく）今日は帰りが遅くなります」 and 「Aチームが多分（おそらく）優勝するだろう」 involving guessing or conjecture, they are interchangeable.  ◇ Both words are also acceptable involving past-tense guessing or conjecture: 「あれは多分おととしの暮れだったと思う」「彼はおそらくその事実を知っていたであろう」 ◇ For 「おそらく」, its original meaning implying a negative nuance or negative potential outcome is still common: 「おそらく後悔するだろう」 ◇ 「多分」sounds more casual, 「おそらく」sounds more polite: 「多分彼は来ないだろう」「おそらく彼は来ないでしょう」 ◇ There is also the related spoken/colloquial word 「きっと」 used in the same way as 「多分」 and 「おそらく」, but which implies a more certain possibility of realization: 「Aチームがきっと優勝するだろう」.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the simple explanation:

1. 恐らく expresses dismay or regret, while 多分 is neutral.
2. 恐らく is more formal, while 多分 sounds more careless and possibly rude.

In other words, 恐らく can be translated as "I'm afraid that..." or "is likely to" (as opposed to "probably").